# Testing Analysis services

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, ssas

We are looking to build a cube in Microsft SQL server analysis services but would like to be able to use some of the automated testing infrastructure we have.

such as Cruise control for automated build, deployments and test.

I am looking for anyone that can give me any pointers on building tests against analysis services, and also any experience with adding these to a build pipeline.

Also if automation is not possible some manual test methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I came upon [BI.Quality](http://biquality.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex and from what I can tell it's very easy to learn and to integrate into existing deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

There is another framework named [NBi](http://nbi.codeplex.com). You've additional features compared to BI.Quality as to check the existence of a measure, dimension, attributes, the order of members, the count of members. Also when comparing two result sets it's often easier to spot the difference between them with NBi. The edition of the test-suites is also done in one single xml file validated by an XSD (better user-experience).